# GPT4-vision OCR enhancements returns error 400

Tags: azure, azure-openai

I am testing with the GPT4 OCR Vision (model version: gpt-4 vision preview),

- use postman send API with OCR enhancement body like the API document claimed "enhancements":{ "ocr":{"enabled":true}, "grounding":{"enabled":true} }, "dataSources":[ { "type":"AzureComputerVision", "parameters":{ "endpoint":"https://xyz.cognitiveservices.azure.com", "key":"xyz" } } ]However, I got 400 model error "message": "1 validation error for Request\nbody -> enhancements\n extra fields not permitted (type=value_error.extra)", "type": "invalid_request_error",Azure OpenAI Service REST API reference - Azure OpenAI | Microsoft Learn

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/openai/reference#example-request-2

Can you please help with the OCR enhancement with API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the the following URI path {base_url}/extensions/chat/completions for OCR enhancements.

I'm using the sample below (python) and it's working properly!!!
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/openai/gpt-v-quickstart?tabs=image&pivots=rest-api

```
    # Packages required:
import requests 
import json 

api_base = '<your_azure_openai_endpoint>' 
deployment_name = '<your_deployment_name>'
API_KEY = '<your_azure_openai_key>'

base_url = f"{api_base}openai/deployments/{deployment_name}" 
headers = {   
    "Content-Type": "application/json",   
    "api-key": API_KEY 
} 

# Prepare endpoint, headers, and request body 
endpoint = f"{base_url}/extensions/chat/completions?api-version=2023-12-01-preview" 
data = {
    "model": "gpt-4-vision-preview",
    "enhancements": {
        "ocr": {
          "enabled": True
        },
        "grounding": {
          "enabled": True
        }
    },
    "dataSources": [
    {
        "type": "AzureComputerVision",
        "parameters": {
            "endpoint": "<your_computer_vision_endpoint>",
            "key": "<your_computer_vision_key>"
        }
    }],
    "messages": [ 
        { "role": "system", "content": "You are a helpful assistant." }, 
        { "role": "user", 
        "content": [  
            { 
                "type": "text", 
                "text": "Describe this picture:" 
            },
            { 
                "type": "image_url", 
                "image_url": {
                    "url" : "<URL or base 64 encoded image>"
                }
            }
        ]} 
    ], 
    "max_tokens": 2000 
}   

# Make the API call   
response = requests.post(endpoint, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data))   

print(f"Status Code: {response.status_code}")   
print(response.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

I can able to reproduce your issue by simply removing the `extensions` in the URL. Even i did the same mistake in the first try :)

One can easily make this mistake for `Enhanced chat with vision` which requires a different endpoint which is `extensions` on top of `chat/completions`

So the correct endpoint to call this feature is

`https://YOUR_RESOURCE_NAME.openai.azure.com/openai/deployments/YOUR_DEPLOYMENT_NAME/extensions/chat/completions?api-version=2023-12-01-preview`

Make sure you add **extensions**